# Magit: stash push

Tags: magit

The stash "push" command is really practical, while stash "save" is supposed to be deprecated. However, on magit I can just find stash save... Is there any reason for that? Did I miss something?

```
Switches
 -u Also save untracked files (--include-untracked)
 -a Also save untracked and ignored files (--all)

Actions
 z Save                  Z Snapshot              p Pop
 i Save index            I Snapshot index        a Apply
 w Save worktree         W Snapshot worktree     l List
 x Save keeping index    r Snapshot to wipref    v Show
 b Branch                k Drop                  
 f Format patch
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's deprecated with the commit [fd2ebf14db52c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/commit/?id=fd2ebf14db52cc41e1cd39b1532d03cb1a702d47), which follows v2.15.0-rc2.  Given that the current git is 2.16.1, as of this writing, Magit author needs a bit of time to fix it up.  Meanwhile, you could fill an issue on [github](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues) to help him track it.

Comment: Remember that Magit supports Git versions 1.9.4 and above.

Comment: Oh, I though it was older than that. I filled as you proposed an issue here https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3349

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answering based on https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3349 )

From my reading, the single difference of note between `git stash save` and `git stash push` is the ability to include optional `<pathspec>` arguments in the latter.

You can already achieve this effect in Magit by staging the things you wish to stash, and then stashing the index.

(n.b. Magit implements its own *custom* stashing features, including stashing just the index, or just the un-staged changes.)

As `git stash push` also ([apparently](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3200#issuecomment-338155609)) utilises the index, it doesn't look like Magit has anything to gain by using `stash push`.

Comment: Thanks! I was also thinking that magit was using deprecated stuff, but in fact it seems that magit just implemented stash save without using stash save... So no problem. Thanks!